# Disable throwing exceptions for E_USER_WARNING

Tags: php, laravel, exception, laravel-5

Laravel is returning a 500 when I do:

```
trigger_error("Some message", E_USER_WARNING);
```

I need it to *not* error out, but I *do* want it to run through `\App\Exceptions\Handler::report` which logs the warning to Sentry.

How do I disable turning warnings and errors into exceptions with Laravel 5.2?

Comment: it wont trigger 500 error, you sure you not missed the ; after the line?

Comment: @Exprator I'm sure it's not a syntax error, and it most definitely throws an `ErrorException` and goes through `\App\Exceptions\Handler::render` which returns a response on the spot rather than continuing like I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could edit laravel's error handler to only report warnings in [`HandleExceptions.php`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/f61a75d2a3a0cd99ec2e28d3d3de2753824df876/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php#L58)

```
public function handleError($level, $message, $file = '', $line = 0, $context = [])
{
    $exception = new ErrorException($message, 0, $level, $file, $line);

    if (E_USER_WARNING & $level) {
        $this->getExceptionHandler()->report($exception);
    }
    elseif (error_reporting() & $level) {
        throw $exception;
    }
}
```

User Warning: Modifying vendor code is usually a bad idea.

You can avoid modifying vendor code by extending the `HandleExceptions` class and registering your new class in [`Kernel.php`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/bd352a0d2ca93775fce8ef02365b03fc4fb8cbb0/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php#L39)

```
MyHandleExceptions extends HandleExceptions {
    public function handleError($level, $message, $file = '', $line = 0, $context = [])
    {   
        if (E_USER_WARNING & $level) {
            $this->getExceptionHandler()->report(new ErrorException($message, 0, $level, $file, $line));
        }
        else {
            return parent::handleError($level, $message, $file, $line, $context);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would I have to overwrite the entirety of [`$bootstrappers`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/2a79f920d5584ec6df7cf996d922a742d11095d1/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php#L40) to register my custom error handler?

Comment: @mpen yes copy all of `$bootstrappers` to `app/Http/Kernel.php` and replace HandleExceptions

Comment: Another way to override it would be to use register it as a singleton in the app as: 

`$app->singleton(\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::class, App\Exceptions\AppHandleExceptions::class);` in your `bootstrap/app.php`

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't display the normal content of the page when you are inside the ErrorHandler, you have to throw another error message:

```
Route::get('error', function() {
    $client = new Raven_Client(env("SENTRY_DSN"));
    $client->captureMessage("Some Warning", ['log'], [
        'level' => 'warning'
    ]);
});
```

This will create a custom warning entry for sentry without throwing a real error in php that would stop your normal code.

you could also wrap it in a function

```
function trigger_sentry_warning($message) {
    $client = new Raven_Client(env("SENTRY_DSN"));
    $client->captureMessage($message, ['log'], [
        'level' => 'warning'
   ]);
}
```

Comment: So....basically I can't use `trigger_error`? That's pretty shitty because I've done this plenty in my non-Laravel apps. If Laravel didn't [throw an `ErrorException`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/bd352a0d2ca93775fce8ef02365b03fc4fb8cbb0/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php#L60) from `set_error_handler` and just handled it properly inside there, everything would have been fine.

Comment: You could overwrite the trigger_error function to implement the missing logic

Comment: What do you mean "overwrite" the trigger_error function? You mean with that APD PECL extension? I don't think that's a good approach.

Comment: You can check in the error handler, if it's a warning or not, but you can got back to continue the code. When Laravel is inside the errorhandler it wants to generate a new view, so logging with sentry has to be outside this class. With overwriting I mean, that you declare the function again and put your check inside it so you don't have to replace it everywhere

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be handled by php. did you try  error_reporting()?
[set_error_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)

more information:

> Out of the box, Laravel supports writing log information to single files, daily files, the syslog, and the errorlog. To configure which storage mechanism Laravel uses, you should modify the log option in your config/app.php configuration file. For example, if you wish to use daily log files instead of a single file, you should set the log value in your app configuration file to daily

[laravel error and logging](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/errors)

Comment: Setting `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_USER_WARNING)` prevents `\App\Exceptions\Handler::report` from being called. Where would I move the Sentry error handling if I use this approach?

Comment: i don't know about sentry. but you can catch any exception in handler with `if ($exception instanseof ExceptionType)` and/or checking another details. then you can send sentry logs in the body of if statement.

Comment: Where? Where would I put that if condition? Because by the time it hits `\App\Exceptions\Handler::report` is already too late -- I can't recover from there and continue to the normal code flow. This is the entire problem.

Comment: yes! you cannot go back from there. you can just send a message to user. just add this logic to the render() function.